# How do I view ovl files on Geogrid or Top50 then convert the data to shapefiles?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, fme-form, overlay, ascii

I have some .ovl files which can only opened on Geogrid or Top50 viewer which shows me where everything is. How do I take these ovl files and convert the properties to Shapefiles to be used on ArcMap 10.1?

I also have access to FME but that does not seem like it can straight up open ovl files.

Answer (score 1):

The ovl format is specific to Germany and Austria. For more information, click [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/DE:OVL) 
The best way that I have found to convert these to shapefiles is to use [gpsies](http://www.gpsies.com/upload.do?uploadMode=convert) , convert to kml, then use ArcGIS to convert to layer. Another software that I have found to be useful is [KML Manager](http://www.mchme.com/cms/) but you only get a 21 day free trial.

Comment: If it's a German format, and you have FME, then try contacting someone at con terra (http://www.conterra.de/index_en.asp) - they may already have a solution to read it.